# Как обработать клик по элементу в RecyclerView Android?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня посредством RecyclerView в сетке выводятся изображения.

Как назначить слушатель клика на изображение с дальнейшим показом его на полный экран?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.serv_url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                int count = 0;
                while (count < response.length()) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                        arrayList.add(new Album(jsonObject.getString("id"), jsonObject.getString("title")));
                        count++;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList, MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getmInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQue(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java:**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<Album> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Activity activity;
        public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Album> arrayList, Context context) {
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            activity = (Activity) context;
        }
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.Title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            String path = Config.img_path + arrayList.get(position).getId();
          Glide.with(activity).load(path).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.notfound).into(holder.Thumbnail);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }
        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ImageView Thumbnail;
            TextView Title;
            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                Thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.album_title);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что представляет из себя класс RecyclerAdapter?

Comment: @Werder Привел код

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface OnThumbnailClickListener {
   void onThumbnailClick(String path);
}

public RecyclerAdapter(..., OnThumbnailClickListener listener) {
   ...
   this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
   ...
   final String path = ...
   ...
   holder.Thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      void onClick(View view) {listener.onThumbnailClick(path)}
   });
}

new RecyclerAdapter(..., new OnThumbnailClickListener(){...})
```